# ¿Como dibujar una linea sobre una imagen en Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

Necesitamos dibujar una linea sobre una imagen en el programa Qt

Comment: Por favor, podrías indicar ¿[Qué has intentado](https://medium.com/@unrob/que-has-intentado-12b31d36bc89#.i16zauc9h) hasta ahora? ¿Tienes algún ejemplo del código que estáis usando? ¿para qué plataforma es la aplicación? ¿Estáis usando Qt creator u otro IDE? ¿qué version de Qt creator estáis usando?

Comment: Hola Alicia, bienvenida, por favor lee por acá http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask consejos de como escribir una buena pregunta, recuerda que mientras mas información nos des, de mejor manera y mas rápido te podremos ayudar. saludos

Comment: Bienvenida al sitio @Alicia. Por favor brinda más detalles de tu pregunta. Esto ayudará a los miembros de la comunidad a apoyarte a resolver tu problema. Conviene también mostrar si has intentado resolverlo de alguna manera.

Answer (score 1):

Para dibujar una línea:

```
void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::black, 12, Qt::DashDotLine, Qt::RoundCap));
    painter.drawLine(0, 0, 200, 200);
}
```